# How to test with Web@Work from MobileIron in a development environment?

Tags: mobile-development

I have a website that works perfectly in any browser.

Now I want to use the Web@Work browser from MobileIron to use this website as a boorkmark to create a basic iOS application packaged thanks to MobileIron.

The basic presentation of Web@Work is here: https://www.mobileiron.com/en/products/webwork

I would like to find a way to develop with Web@Work locally, like that I would be able to track bugs easily.

Comment: Léo, I'm sorry, but can please explain a little bit more in detail what you would like to do? Do you want to integrate Web@Work in you app? Would you like to access or install your app from the mentioned website?

Comment: I want to debug locally with Web@Work, with my own PC, like I usually do with other browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Web@Work is a dual-mode app. This means that if it is installed on a device with MobileIron infrastructure, it uses MobileIron for security and management (AppConnect mode). If that infrastructure is absent, it works in standalone mode (non-AppConnect mode) and it is not secured or managed by MobileIron.

If I understand your question correctly, you're making a site and want to verify that it works properly with Web@Work. You should be able to do that by just installing the browser app from iTunes and browsing like you would with any other browser.

Comment: Sure, I can browse with Web@Work ;-) The question is how to debug it, e.g. using Safari Developer Tools remotely as I can with Safari. There seems no way to find out why a page is not shown properly in Web@Work

Comment: @nachtigall WebInspector (Safari Tools) works with all UIWebViews instances including Web@Work, although I haven't tried it myself.

Comment: Yeah the web at work window doesn't show up in the Developer menu when I've connected it to my macbook. Anybody have ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is not possible this way. If you would like to access an intranet web site behind a MobileIron Sentry and want to debug the traffic, you have to build your own custom browser with MobileIron SDK included. I assume there is nothing really special in the Web@Work Browser, because it is distributed via Apple AppStore, therefore they can't do really magic things inside and also have to use UIWebView for rendering web pages.

Answer (score 0):

Apple does not allow to attach and debug(with a WebInspector) a UIWebView present in AppStore App.This is a apple limitation and the same applies for any other browser dowloaded from AppStore not just Web@Work.