# How to install and test Web@Work from MobileIron on Android?

Tags: android, mdm, mobile-development, mobileiron

I want to test my website on MobileIron's Web@Work browser on Android but cannot see it in the Android Market Place.

This previous question gave an answer for iOS (Web@Work is downloadable from the App Store): 
[How to test with Web@Work from MobileIron in a development environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29928665/how-to-test-with-webwork-from-mobileiron-in-a-development-environment)

How do you install Web@Work browser on Android?
And can it be used to browse to URLs directly without any special sign-in or registration, as it does on iOS.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Web@work can be installed from Apps@work screen in Mobile@work app if your admin has allowed you to install and access. Your admin can help by pushing that app to device by assigning a label and you can install the same from Mobile@work app on your device.

Second part of your question is related to authentication while accessing webpages.  If your webpage doesn't have any authentication , Web@Work will not ask any credentials. If your webpage needs authentication , you can set up KCD with MobileIron to have seamless authentication. Please refer to the documentation for more detail.The below post capture few details:
[MobileIron with sharepoint for authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28988121/mobileiron-with-sharepoint-for-authentication)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Chandra. What you stated is true. What I also needed to know (that we later discovered) is that the MobileIron Cloud product can not install Web@Work to Android. The wrappers are incompatible. Only the Core product can do that. That was part of the problem we had.